# Suddenly the pytube library stopped working with nothing and began to issue an error

Tags: python, pytube

When trying to use this code, an error pops up

```
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
yt=YouTube(link)
t=yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
t[0].download('temp/audio.mp3')
```

The error itself:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\olimpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\olimpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\olimpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 33, in __init__
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Scripts\Bot Kit\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    t=yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
      ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\olimpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\olimpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 188, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\olimpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\olimpa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 33, in __init__
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: __init__: could not find match for ^\w+\W

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried reinstalling the library several times. Nothing came of it, the error did not disappear

Comment: Known issue, see [#1754](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1754) and [#1757](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1757). TLDR: Probably a change on YouTubes site, so the parser doesn't work correctly anymore (see [this comment](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1754#issuecomment-1675747701))

Comment: For your future knowledge, YouTube changes their metadata structure quite often.  When they do, that breaks the scrapers like `pytube`.  When this happens, you always need to go to the `pytube` site to get an update.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has recently introduces. You can do a temporary fix until the pytube library is updated. Change the regex in **cipher.py** at line 30

```
var_regex = re.compile(r"^\$*\w+\W")
```

I am downloading the highest quality audio available in the streams

```
yt = YouTube(url)
content = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).order_by('abr').desc().first()
content.download()
```

This worked for me!